# Central Limit Theorem for Triangular Array of independent Bernoulli Variables.

Tags: convergence-divergence, random-variables, central-limit-theorem

Let $B_{j,n}$ with $j=0,\ldots,n$ be a triangular array of independent Bernoulli random variables such that

$$
\mathbb{P}\left[B_{j,n}=1\right]=p_n,\quad \mathbb{P}\left[B_{j,n}=0\right]=1-p_n
$$

with $p_n$ a sequence such that $p_n\rightarrow p$ when $n\rightarrow\infty$. Consider now the random variable

$$
z_{j,n} = \frac{B_{j,n}-p_n}{B_{j-1,n}-p_n},\quad j=1,\ldots,n.
$$
Clearly the $z_{j,n}$ are dependent random variables and

$$
\mu_{j,n}=\mathbb{E}[z_{j,n}\mid B_{j-1,n}] = 0. 
$$

I am looking for a central limit theorem for

$$
S_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\,\sum_{j=1}^nz_{j,n}
$$
but being the z's dependent I cannot find a simple result. The paper by Dvoretzky (http://digitalassets.lib.berkeley.edu/math/ucb/text/math_s6_v2_article-30.pdf) says that it would be enough that

$$
\sum_{j=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\,\mathbb{E}\left[z_{j,n}^2\mid B_{j-1,n}\right]\stackrel{p}{\longrightarrow} 1,\quad (1)
$$
(plus other two conditions that for now I am omitting). Nevertheless using Markov's inequality I am not able to prove (1), any hint? Do someone know a simple result on central limit theorem for triangular arrays of dependent random variables?

Comment: Assuming each sequence $(B_{j,n})_j$ is independent and replacing the conditional expectations in the LHS of (1) by their value, one sees that it converges almost surely to $\sigma^2=\frac{p^3+(1-p)^3}{p(1-p)}$ hence indeed $(S_n)$ satisfies a central limit theorem, but with a variance $\sigma^2>1$.

Comment: Sorry, the $(B_{j,n})_{j=1,...,n}$ are independent, I have modified the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since $B_j$s are iid,

\begin{align} 
\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}[z_{j,n}^2 \, | \, B_{j-1,n}]& = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \mathbb{E}\left[ \left(\frac{B_{j,n}-p_n}{B_{j-1,n}-p_n}\right)^2 \, | \, B_{j-1,n}\right] 
 = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[ \left(B_{j,n}-p_n\right)^2 \, | \, B_{j-1,n}\right]}{\left(B_{j-1,n}-p_n\right)^2} \\
& = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\mathbb{E}\left[ \left(B_{j,n}-p_n\right)^2 \right]}{\left(B_{j-1,n}-p_n\right)^2}  = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{p_n(1-p_n)}{\left(B_{j-1,n}-p_n\right)^2} 
\end{align}

Now, to show convergence in probability to 1, for any $\varepsilon>0$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}\left[ \Bigg| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{p_n(1-p_n)}{\left(B_{j-1,n}-p_n\right)^2}-1 \Bigg| > \varepsilon \right] &= \mathbb{P}\left[ \Bigg| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{\left(B_{j-1,n}-p_n\right)^2}- \frac{1}{p_n(1-p_n)} \Bigg| > \frac{\varepsilon}{p_n(1-p_n)} \right] \\  
 &= \mathbb{P}\left[ \Bigg| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\left(B_{j-1,n}-p_n\right)^2 - p_n(1-p_n)}{\left(B_{j-1,n}-p_n\right)^2 } \Bigg|  > {\varepsilon} \right] \\  
 & \leq \mathbb{P}\left[ \Bigg| \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n {\left(B_{j-1,n}-p_n\right)^2 - p_n(1-p_n)} \Bigg|  > \frac{\varepsilon}{\min\{p_n^2, (1-p_n)^2 \}} \right] \\ 
& \to 0 \text{ by weak law of large numbers.}
\end{align}

Comment: I did not understand where the last inequality comes from, can you explain with more details?